# Unable to boot custom kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I am using ubuntu 11.04

I have a custom 2.6.36.4 kernel source (say in `linux_src`)

Did `make mrproper`
Copied my current  configuration from `/boot` to `linux_src/.config`
Did a `make menuconfig`, instructed it to load the configuration file `.config`. 
In general setup, I added the string `rr` to the kernel version number.
Exited the configuration.

Did a `make  && make modules_install && make install` as superuser.
This created the vmlinuz-2.6.36.4rr image in /boot; the corresponding directory in /lib/modules. System.map in /boot, but not initrd image

So I ran the following command :

`cd /boot && sudo mkinitramfs -k -o initrd.img-2.6.36.4rr`

Finally I ran `sudo update-grub`. Grub found my new linux image and the new initrd image.

On booting, the newly installed kernel was listed in my boot options. I selected it, and then the screen went blank (but not *black*, it just showed some default ubuntu theme colored blank screen) and stuck there.

I suspect the makeinitramfs process was the culprit.

On the other hand when I had installed the same kernel using `make-kpkg` and `dpkg` I had to do no other thing, (not even initramfs) and the kernel had booted perfectly (I *don't* want to use this method to install kernel).

Please help.

EDIT : I made some progress

Instead of using :

`cd /boot && sudo mkinitramfs -k -o initrd.img-2.6.36.4rr`
I used 
`cd /boot && sudo mkinitramfs -k -o initrd.img-2.6.36.4rr 2.6.36.4rr`

which i believe is the correct way to use mkinitramfs.

However, now my  boot process ends at "gave up waiting for the root device" and an initramfs prompt

Comment: What happens if you remove `quiet` and `slash` from the kernel command line, and add `init=/bin/sh`?

Comment: @Giles do I need to configure 1) /etc/default/grub; or 2) /boot/grub/grub.cfg to make the above changes ?

Comment: @AnkurVj You don't need to permanently edit grub menu file (which is No 2 from your question). You can modify the kernel command line by pressing **`c`** while in grub boot menu (when booting).

Answer (score 3):

Reading your description, I see you did not do one important thing in the configuration phase: `make oldconfig` after copying the `.config` file, but before doing `make menuconfig` (BTW, if the configuration is saved in `.config` file in the sources directory, you don;t need to explicitly load it - that is done by default). This is needed in all cases when the new kernel version is at least a bit different then the one where `.config` came from.

I'm not sure about your initramfs creation method - the only one I've ever used was with `genkernel`. But to determine if the initramfs is the culprit, you can just modify grub entry to point to the old initramfs file (the one used by your current system). Also, When the system is booting, you can often press <kbd>F1</kbd> to see the boot messages (might need to remove `quiet` from bootloader menu entry first).

*Edit:*
Just a thought: there could be a problem with your grub menu entry (found in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `/boot/grub/grub.conf`) - compare the old and new one, maybe the kernel parameters are wrong (like wrong `real_root`). Simply speaking, the lines after `kernel` should be the same apart from the kernel location and initrd.

Comment: I have edit my question. Please have a look

Comment: Yes, I see... But did you try any of the things suggested in my answer?